# Jquery - Validation error message doesn't go for after the field is disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to create a mandatory field in a form. The mandatory check is required only when a checkbox is unchecked. My problem is

1. form loaded
2. click save button
3. hit the validation checks and display error message
4. when checked the "Checkbox", the text field is disabled. but the validation error message still appear

I want the validation error to disappear for that particular field when checkbox is checked. Here are my codes.

```
    <tr><td>
      <label for="Name">Employer's Name : </label>
      <span class="error"> * </span></td> 
        <td>input type="text" id="Name"  name="Name" value="" maxlength="66" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
       <input type='checkbox' id="C4" name='C4' value='' onClick='javascript:click()' />
       <label for="C4">Please check</label>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

---

```
   function click() {
var checked = $("input[name='C4']").is(':checked');
if ( checked == true){
      $("input[name='Name']").prop("disabled", true);
      $("input[name='Name']").valid();
    }       
else
{     $("input[name='Name']").prop("disabled", false);
     } }
```

---

```
    $('form[name="question"]').validate({
     success: function(error) {  // change CSS on your element(s) back to normal
     error.removeClass("error");
        },
     rules: {
           Name: {   
                        required: "#C4:unchecked" }
            }

        , submitHandler: function(form) {
        if(validate()){
            form.submit();
            }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Where is the rest of this?   You've stripped it down so far, there is nothing left to create a working demo.  What about the `.validate()` method?  The `form` tags?  Where is the function that calls your if/then conditional and how is that triggered?

Comment: @Sparky I have updated my codes. Please help to take a look and suggest any solution to the problem plz

Comment: Please do not ask new questions within the comments section.  Only post a new question as a new question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loads of issues here in your code...

```
$('form[name="question"]').validate({
    success: function(error) { 
        error.removeClass("error");  // <- no, no, no!!
    },
    rules: {
        Name: {   
            required: "#C4:unchecked"  // should be true, false, or a function
        }
    }, 
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        if(validate()){    // <- invalid syntax and NOT needed here
            form.submit(); // <- DEFAULT behavior
        }
    }
} // <- missing closing );
```

1. `error.removeClass("error")` would only remove the class from the error message label and nothing else.  Regardless, you do not need to remove the `error` class within the `success` function, because this is done automatically by the plugin.  If you wanted to over-ride how classes are applied, you'd only use `hightlight` and `unhighlight` callbacks.  The `success` callback is only used if you want to show the error message label when the field is valid... like for a green checkmark.
2. The `required` rule only takes a `true`, `false`, or a function, never a jQuery selector.  In your case, you write a function that checks whether the checkbox is ticked and returns `true` or `false` based on that condition...

   ```
   rules: {
       Name: {
           required: function() {
               return !$('#C4').is(':checked');
           }
       }
   },
   ```
3. Within your `submitHandler`, `if (validate())` is nonsense in two ways.  One, you don't need to test for validity here because the `submitHandler` only fires if the form is valid.  And two, `validate()` is meaningless... it's not a valid argument, keyword, function, or method.
4. You're missing the closing `);` after the brace at the end of the method.  `.validate({...});`
5. Within your table, you are missing the opening bracket `<` on this element:

   ```
   input type="text" id="Name"  name="Name" value="" maxlength="66" size="30" />
   ```
6. You do not need `onClick='javascript:click()'`, when you can simply use a jQuery `click` handler function.

   ```
   $('#C4').on('click', function() {
       var nameField = $('#Name');
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           nameField.prop("disabled", true);
       } else {
           nameField.prop("disabled", false);
       }
       nameField.valid();
   });
   ```
7. You do not need a `submitHandler` if the only line within this function is `form.submit()`.  This is the default behavior so you can remove the whole thing.

---

**Working version:**

```
$('form[name="question"]').validate({
    rules: {
        Name: {
            required: function() {
                return !$('#C4').is(':checked');
            }
        }
    }
});

$('#C4').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#Name').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('#Name').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    $('#Name').valid();
});
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/7L2rm0gu/](http://jsfiddle.net/7L2rm0gu/)

Answer (score 0):

If you add some class in disable given trick works.

```
    validator.resetForm();
    var checked = $("input[name='C4']").is(':checked');
    if ( checked == true){
          $("input[name='Name']").prop("disabled", true);
          $("input[name='Name']").addClass("dis");
          $("input[name='Name']").valid();
        }       
    else
    {     $("input[name='Name']").prop("disabled", false);
          $("input[name='Name']").removeClass("dis");
    }
```

And on rule :

```
ignore: ".dis, :hidden",
Name: {
    required: "#C4:unchecked" ,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but that didnt work for me.. any other suggestion? plz

Comment: You absolutely cannot put the `ignore` option anyplace inside of the rules object... it's a sibling of `rules`.   And the `required` rule can only get `true` or `false` as its parameter, not a jQuery selector.

Comment: @Sparky I have updated my codes. Please help to take a look and suggest any solution to the problem plz